# How to resolve "permission denied" when emptying the trash?

Tags: permissions, trash

I installed a game, and then decided to erase it. I sent it to the recycle bin, but I was unable to delete it completely (Permission denied). When I moved it back to the desktop, a copy remained in the recycle.
I sent it back to the bin, and back to the desktop; so I ended with 2 copies of the file in the bin, and one on the desktop.
Finally I noticed that a file inside the game was protected. I changed the permission settings to the desktop copy and I was able to erase it completely, but I was not able to change the permission settings on the 2 copies I still have in the bin (the backend do not support the operation)

I just want to empty the recycle bin!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following command will empty the trash

```
sudo rm -rv .local/share/Trash/
```

And when you don't want any prompts with 'Do you want to delete write protected file x?' add the -f option.

```
sudo rm -rvf .local/share/Trash/
```

Comment: Can you set set my answer as 'Accepted answer'? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 20. Should this be run from within the home directory of the root user?!

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to first change permissions in the Trash folder
(and then to empty it in the usual way:)

```
cd ~/.local/share/Trash
sudo chown -R your_user_name:your_group *
```

(And then empty it the usual way)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even had local Trash folder, for me solution was to create it and than give permissions to local user over everything in that folder.

```
mkdir /home/(username)/.local/share/Trash
```

and than:

```
sudo chown -R username:username Trash/
```